# Jquery AutoComplete initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Let's say I have the following data feeding to jquery autocomplete.

```
var data = [
        { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
        { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
        { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" }
    ];
```

How could I make Alaska as the default selection. I am getting the "AK" from server side as the existing selection and I need to somehow show Alaska in the autocomplete input box based on the value coming from server side.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you,
Sri

Comment: Can we see your server side script?  You need to return the labels instead of the values...

Comment: It is java code and not yet written the code. I will be returning JSON data back from server side. The data will be in label value pairs to get populate in autocomplete and the selected value as separate field.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Autocomplete widget does not have an API to do that.

But you can simply set the `label` and `value` of the `input` tag where you're applying jquery autocomplete, apart from putting it in the `data` variable as you've shown. That'll get the job done.

Something like:

`<input label="Alaska" value="AK">...`

If you wan't this to be dynamic between several server calls, set label and value using jquery right before you call autocomplete on it.